# How to generate alternating substrings using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a practice question that requires me to generate x number of alternating substrings, namely "#-" & "#--" using both recursion as well as iteration. Eg.string_iteration(3) generates "#-#--#-".

I have successfully implemented the solution for the iterative method,
but I'm having trouble getting started on the recursive method. How can I proceed?

**Iterative method**

```
def string_iteration(x):
    odd_block = '#-'
    even_block = '#--'
    current_block = ''
    if x == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            if i % 2 != 0:
                current_block += odd_block
            elif i % 2 == 0:
                current_block += even_block
            i += 1
        return current_block
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: _I have successfully implemented the solution for the iterative method, but im having trouble getting started on the recursive method. Any pointers please?_ Learn more about recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recursion, you almost always just need a base case and everything else. Here, your base case it pretty simple — when x < 1, you can return an empty string:

```
if x < 1:
    return ''
```

After than you just need to return the block + the result of `string_iteration(x-1)`. After than it's just a matter of deciding which block to choose. For example:

```
def string_iteration(x):
    # base case
    if x < 1:      
        return '' 

    blocks = ('#--', '#-')
    # recursion
    return string_iteration(x-1) + blocks[x % 2] 

string_iteration(5)
# '#-#--#-#--#-'
```

This boils down to

```
string_iteration(1) + string_iteration(2) ... string_iteration(x)
```

Comment: Ahh okay blocks[ x % 2] makes sense as i was initially having trouble selecting which block to choose. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For recursive solution, you need a base case and calling the function again with some other value so that at the end you will have the desired output. Here, we can break this problem recursively like - `string_recursive(x) = string_recursive(x-1) + string_recursive(x-2) + ... + string_recursive(1)`.

```
def string_recursion(x, parity):
    final_str = ''
    if x == 0:
        return ''
    if parity == -1: # when parity -1 we will add odd block
        final_str += odd_block
    elif parity == 1:
        final_str += even_block
    parity *= -1    # flip the parity every time
    final_str += string_recursion(x-1, parity)
    return final_str

odd_block = '#-'
even_block = '#--' 
print(string_recursion(3, -1)) # for x=1 case we have odd parity, hence -1
# Output: #-#--#-
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but the reason might be because having a recursive function depend on a global variable is a pretty big code smell. Also, people downvote code-only answers — that's discouraged here. Also, you get an infinite recursion if you pass a negative value in.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks, can you please tell me the good practice instead of using a global variable? I am learning to write reusable and maintainable code.

Comment: You don't really need a state variable here, as you can see above. But if you do, it's generally better to pass it as an argument to the function. Then the recursive calls pass it in as well (and change it if needed).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer doesn't give the same result as your iterative method. If you always want it to start with the odd block, you should add the block on the right of the recursive call instead of the left:

```
def string_recursion(x):
    odd_block = '#-'
    even_block = '#--'
    if x == 0:
        return ''
    if x % 2 != 0:
        return string_recursion(x - 1) + odd_block
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return string_recursion(x - 1) + even_block
```